# Check if a child node exists 2 levels deep

Tags: python

I need to check if a json node exists.

```
ownerid = jsonData[0]['owner']['id']
```

If this exists I dont have an issue. There are times when owner node is not there so I have this and it works

```
if("owner" in jdata): #jdata is of type string
     ownerid = jsonData[0]['owner']['id']
else:
     ownerid = jsonData[0]['owner']['id']
```

This will work when owner does not exists.

My issue is when owner node exists but the 'id' node does not because the owner condition is met and id does not exists so my process fails.

Here is the question how do I check for that specific node inside owner.

I can not use

```
if("id" in jdata) #jdata is of type string
```

The search word "id" is very common in file. I will get hits but does not necessarily mean id exists inside owner node. How can I check for id with a specific node so I can determine what to do next

FYI... I tried

```
if("id" in jsonData[0]['owner']) #jsonData of type list
```

got an error

```
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dict.get() avoid NoneType error

```
ownerid = jsonData[0].get('owner',{}).get('id')
if ownerid:
    print('ownerid exist')
else:
    print('ownerid not exist')
```

Comment: flgang your code errored does like the second get. This is the error ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: maybe  ```jsonData[0]``` is None, please show your jsonData.also you can use ```if isinstance(jsonData[0],dict): ownerid = jsonData[0].get('owner',{}).get('id')```

Comment: you were right jsonData[0]['owner'] was none.  I tackled problem little differently i am just checking if owner is null then I check if id for owner is null.If true set to = '' else set to id value. This is working thus far. Thanks!

Comment: I cant add json data as it has proprietary data could get in trouble. Thanks!